# Minimization of the integral with respect to a parameter

Tags: integration, optimization

**Intro** 
Let $f$ be a a real-valued function parametrized by a parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $J\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a functional defined as follows:

$$J(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{x^2 - \alpha}J_0(x) \ dx$$
Function $f$ involves Bessel $J_0$ function [1], so, it has not closed form.

**Problem**
I am looking for a minimization method of the functional $J$ with respect to the parameter $\alpha$.

Of course, $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}$ has no closed form, too.

1. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html, eq. 78

Comment: Why not to plug it into Euler's Equation? Is $x$ a function? Does $f$ depends on $x'$ as well?

Comment: The $x$ is a variable. Function does not depend on $x'$.